# Setting up line-height via TinyMCE

Tags: css, configuration, tinymce

Is there a way to give user possibility to easily changing line-height attribute of paragraph in tinyMCE editor? Something like its native "Font size" or "Format" `<select>` or anything else. I know I can use "edit CSS" functionality and set it up there. I'm looking for something more user-friendly.

I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Could http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=28774 not be of any use to you?

Comment: Please answer with it to my question. I need time to test it. Until then if there are no better solutions here you'll be a winner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per my comment,

Someone else was experiencing an issue similar to yours and a member of the TinyMCE forums provided a solution:

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=28774

Comment: I was going bonkers with this... I'm using tinyMCE to post messages as well as send out emails. I had this issue in emails even after I had used external CSS. The custom plugin thing looks great and I'm hoping it will work because it will insert a "style" attribute which can be understood by outlook... darn MS products.. Thanks.. I'm trying out the solution now.

Comment: Link is now broken.

Comment: @Strategist http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:cTPQyKKwD7YJ:archive.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php%3Fid%3D28774+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=nl

Answer (score 10):

I found this PlugIn for TinyMCE version 4.1.5 (2014-09-09)

https://github.com/castler/tinymce-line-height-plugin

Setting up like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: 'lineheight',
    toolbar: 'lineheightselect' 
});
```

Also you could configure the different heights like that:

```
tinymce.init({
    lineheight_formats: "8pt 9pt 10pt 11pt 12pt 14pt 16pt 18pt 20pt 22pt 24pt 26pt 36pt",
});
```

I tested this and it works great.

Comment: just letting people know this plugin doesn't work in tinymce 5.

Comment: it had been updated to work with TinyMCE 5 on Jun 8, 2019 before @Tom commented.. but perhaps it is buggy? Anyways, 5.5 does support line-height now it seems https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/release-notes/release-notes55/#newlineheightsupportintheeditor

Comment: In tinymce v6 it `line_height_formats`

Answer (score 1):

With TinyMCE 4 you can use "style_formats" option

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:style_formats

Answer (score 1):

I have found a good way for adding custom line-height to tinymce but this is a trick.
I am using  tinymce v5 and with these codes i can use line height with a nice select option.
[image]

you have to add these lines to init codes of tiny mce:

```
 tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            height: 500,
            plugins: 'table wordcount',
            toolbar: '  styleselect ',

            content_css: [
                '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
                '//www.tiny.cloud/css/codepen.min.css'
            ],
    toolbar: 'styleselect'
 content_style: '.lineheight20px { line-height: 20px; }' +
                '.lineheight22px { line-height: 22px; }' +
                '.lineheight24px { line-height: 24px; }' +
                '.lineheight26px { line-height: 26px; }' +
                '.lineheight28px { line-height: 28px; }' +
                '.lineheight30px { line-height: 30px; }' +
                '.lineheight32px { line-height: 32px; }' +
                '.lineheight34px { line-height: 34px; }' +
                '.lineheight36px { line-height: 36px; }' +
                '.lineheight38px { line-height: 38px; }' +
                '.lineheight40px { line-height: 40px; }' +
                '.tablerow1 { background-color: #D3D3D3; }',
            formats: {
                lineheight20px: { selector: 'span,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'lineheight20px' },
                lineheight22px: { selector: 'span,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'lineheight22px' },
                lineheight24px: { selector: 'span,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'lineheight24px' },
                lineheight26px: { selector: 'span,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'lineheight26px' },
                lineheight28px: { selector: 'span,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'lineheight20px' },
                lineheight30px: { selector: 'span,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'lineheight30px' },
                lineheight32px: { selector: 'span,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'lineheight32px' },
                lineheight34px: { selector: 'span,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'lineheight34px' },
                lineheight36px: { selector: 'span,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'lineheight36px' },
                lineheight38px: { selector: 'span,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'lineheight38px' },
                lineheight40px: { selector: 'span,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'lineheight40px' }
            },
            style_formats: [
                { title: 'lineheight20px',format: 'lineheight20px' },
                { title: 'lineheight22px', format: 'lineheight22px' },
                { title: 'lineheight24px', format: 'lineheight24px' },
                { title: 'lineheight26px', format: 'lineheight26px' },
                { title: 'lineheight28px', format: 'lineheight28px' },
                { title: 'lineheight30px', format: 'lineheight30px' },
                { title: 'lineheight32px', format: 'lineheight32px' },
                { title: 'lineheight34px', format: 'lineheight34px' },
                { title: 'lineheight36px', format: 'lineheight36px' },
                { title: 'lineheight38px', format: 'lineheight38px' },
                { title: 'lineheight40px', format: 'lineheight40px' }



]
    });
```

and at the end i have to say you need to find a "paragraph" word in the file of tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js and change it to "line-height" if you want to see the line-height name instead of paragraph name.
this word is in line of 290855 of that file.
and this job is called custom format in tinymce that if you want to find it check this link:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/format-custom/ 
and I have to say you need to add this css codes to your css file:

```
.lineheight22px{
line-height: 22px;
}
.lineheight24px{
    line-height: 24px;
}
.lineheight26px{
    line-height: 26px;
}
.lineheight28px{
    line-height: 28px;
}
.lineheight30px{
    line-height: 30px;
}
.lineheight32px{
    line-height: 32px;
}
.lineheight34px{
    line-height: 34px;
}
.lineheight36px{
    line-height: 36px;
}
.lineheight38px{
    line-height: 38px;
}
.lineheight40px{
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, TinyMCE doesn't have line-height control as it has for font names or font sizes, but you can easily add it with the `style_formats`. I used this config:

```js
// custom formatting is under Format > formats, so make sure it's in your menu (it is, by default)
const editorOptions = {
  // Notice that it overrides Format > formats
  style_formats: [
      {
          title: 'Line height',
          items: [
            {
              title: 'Default',
              inline: 'span',
              // `inline-block` because CSS `line-height` doesn't affect multiline `span`
              styles: { 'line-height': 'normal', display: 'inline-block' }
            },
            {
              title: '40px',
              inline: 'span',
              styles: { 'line-height': '40px', display: 'inline-block' }
            },
            // add as more as you need
          ]
      },
      // ...
  ]  
}
```

[Working example on codepen](https://codepen.io/Alendorff/pen/yLNaEbz)

[TinyMCE style_formats doc](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#style_formats)