# TinyMCE - tinymce in prestashop

Tags: tinymce, prestashop

How change default line-height in TinyMCE v2.1?

```
<p><span style="line-height: 24px;"></span></p>
```

Comment: Look this answer that I have sent to a similar question [link here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595702/setting-up-line-height-via-tinymce/58452925#58452925)

Answer (score 0):

Head over to here: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=28774

I believe this is your answer!