# inline element line-height (span)

Tags: css, html, doctype

is there any chance ( i don't mind dirty evil tricks ) to get the line-height working on inline elements like < span >? I know that my JSFiddle will work with another doctype but thats not possible since i use a lot of html5 elements. Also i cant use inline-block because tinyMCE adds a span for every line.

Heres the little problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/BE7Cz/2/

ps: The case i need this:
In my theme (wordpress) i added the ability to tinyMCE that a user can change the line-height and the font-size. With a little script i change the inline styles with jquery afterwards to class names which i can make responsive. This works great except the problem with the inline line-height

```
$('.wysiwyg p span').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('font-size-' + $(this).css('fontSize'));
    $(this).addClass('line-height-' + $(this).css('lineHeight'));
});
```

It wouldn't be a probleme if the line-height is always bigger than my body line-height but thats not the case.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks a lot guys! :)

Best wishes,
mike

Comment: I can't see any problem with your fiddle. `line-height` property would be applied to *all elements* per Spec.

Comment: add display:inline-block to the style of your span. Good info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829393/why-the-spans-line-height-is-useless

Comment: you can tune tinyMce to add a class to your span, any how, in the main CSS you can set span {display:inline; /*vertical-align:something else than baseline if neede */;}

Comment: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php see this to find out how to custom your spans from within tinyMce :)

Comment: as said the problem with display: inline-block is that i get an break with each span and since tinymce adds a new span for every line you hit shit+enter, its not a posssible solution: @GCyrilllus: thanks ill try that. for classes: iam only use the script cause if i use multiple classes tiny mce always adds the classes and i dont wont the user to always click away the old style and the click again for the new styles.

Comment: Look this answer that I have sent to a similar question [link here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595702/setting-up-line-height-via-tinymce/58452925#58452925)

Answer (score 0):

The span element is an inline element. You will have to add "display:inline-block" to your style of your span.