# How to add a dropdown for line-height selection in tinyMCE for WP 3.9

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am looking for some code which would add a dropdown to my WYSIWYG fields in the WordPress backend through which I would be able to choose an inline line-height for the selected text. I find the tinyMCE documentation very confusing. Additionally it is mostly aimed at TM 3, but WP 3.9 uses the fourth version…

My tinyMCE Plugin looks something like this:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('ad_lineheight', function(editor, url) {

        …

    editor.addButton('ad_lineheight', {
        type: 'splitbutton',
        text: 'line-height',
        icon: false,
        menu: menuval
    });
});
```

How would you integrate the function, which adds inline-styles to the selected input, like so `<span style="line-height: 120%; display: inline-block;">selected text</span>`?

EDIT: I already managed to add the dropdown to the editor, it shows the line-heights I defined programmatically like 80%, 90%, 100% and so on.

EDIT2: With this code I am able to change the line-height:

```
editor.addCommand('lineHeight', function(com, value) {
    var selected    =   tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
    var content     =   '<span style="line-height: '+value+';">' + (selected != '' ? selected : '') + '</span>';
    editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, content);
});

editor.addButton('lineheightselect', function() {
    …
    …
    return {
        type: 'listbox',
        text: 'line-height',
        tooltip: 'line-height',
        values: items,
        fixedWidth: true,
        onclick: function(e) {
            if (e.control.settings.value) {
                editor.execCommand('lineHeight', false, e.control.settings.value);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

But it is not very practical as it ignores inline-styles that are already there leading to code like this:

```
<span class="h3" style="font-size: 90%;"><span style="line-height: 160%;">AND</span></span>
```

Comment: Look this answer that I have sent to a similar question [link here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595702/setting-up-line-height-via-tinymce/58452925#58452925)

Answer (score 2):

this is an old question but I am adding the answer here just in case anyone still need it.
you can use `getNode()` instead of `getContent()`

you command code will be

```
editor.addCommand('lineHeight', function(com, value) {
    var node = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
    $(node).css('line-height', value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom button to TinyMCE editor, you need also to create your style in some CSS stylesheet. Maybe some WP function may be needed. I don't think you will need adding anything in JS - there is already possibility to add custom style button in TinyMCE and you could achieve that using PHP.

http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons
http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles

Comment: Thank you. See my edit. I already have a dropdown functionality. What you posted would only help if I needed a simple button.