# Adding Line Height Drop Down to Tiny MCE Editor Tool Bar

Tags: tinymce, editor

We are using BlogEngine.Net for managing blog posts which has implemented version “3.9.2” of Tiny MCE Editor.

As per our requirement we want to add new control (dropdown) in tool bar of the editor to provide this line height option so that author of the blog post could set line height to any of the selected paragraphs. We even find a related link for this http://fiddle.tinymce.com/jAbaab but it didn’t work for me.

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Can some one give me some example for code snippets which i can use?

Comment: I am not sure where to look for style plugins in TinyMCE3.

Comment: Look this answer that I have sent to a similar question [link here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595702/setting-up-line-height-via-tinymce/58452925#58452925)

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at the way the style plugin works that gets shipped with Tinymce3. You can copy the plugin directory and apply your own changes there.
All you need to to is to get rid of the unwanted funtionality and rename the plugin (directory and in the code).

Answer (score 0):

This TinyMCE plugin can help you. 
https://github.com/castler/tinymce-line-height-plugin

Download and place it into your tinymce plugin folder.

It supports TinyMCE 4.