# TinyMCE / CKEditor line-height not implemented correctly

Tags: css, ckeditor, tinymce, wysiwyg, font-size

I have an issue with WYSIWYG editors like TinyMCE or CKEditor that they does not format line-height intuitively like standard text editors.

When changing the font-size in WordPad, Google Docs or any standard text editor, the **line-height always matches a line font-size** and not the just a font-size of it's wrapper block:

### Expected behaviour - Google Docs:

[image]

Unfortunately, TinyMCE or CKEditor are too simplistic in this area so they set the font-size by wrapping the selected text into inline span. And inline elements cannot have different line-height set.
While I understand the requirement of a clean code, the result is not what a regular user expects.

### Wrong behaviour - TinyMCE

[image]

### Wrong behaviour - CKEditor

[image]

My clients are rightly surprised that such basic feature is not implemented by default and we need to dig into editor's JS code to achieve the correct line-height formatting.

Any solution to fix it?

Comment: Look at this answer that I have sent to a similar question [link here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595702/setting-up-line-height-via-tinymce/58452925#58452925)